# Как сделать пуш и коммит скриптом пайтон

Tags: python, python-3.x, git, github

Условие когда делать коммит и пуш:
git push ссылка на репозиторий

всё это нужно прописать в main.py

как это реализовать?
и есть ли другие решения моей задачи?

Comment: чел, библиотека gitpython гуглится по твоему вопросу, если делать по-другому - через os можно отправлять команды в терминал

Answer (score 0):

Проще было бы сделать это через bat, но если у вас тяга именно к питону, то тогда рекомендую ознакомиться с бибилиотекой **os**

С её помощью вы сможете испольховать следующий синтаксис:

```
import os

os.system("git add .")
os.system(f'git commit -m "{commit_name}"')
os.system("git push")
```